Expo : content:// uri FileSystem.copyAsync Permission denied in Android when open file in other apps
I want to 'open with' my application when user wants to open pdf, so I added intent filters in manifest xml and created +native-intent.ts to get pdf path in FileProvider. It works when opening from 'My Files' which is default native file manager in Android.
But When I open the file from other apps, like Kakaotalk or Slack, and copy that content:// file into file:// which is in cache directory, the error below occurs.
I tried to make native module to call currentActivity.grantUriPermission(currentActivity.packageName, uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION), but it did not work (java.lang.SecurityException: UID 10874 does not have permission to content)
code where error occured
async function copySharedPathToUri(contentUri: string) {
  const destinationUri = FileSystem.cacheDirectory + "tempFile";
  await FileSystem.copyAsync({
    from: contentUri,
    to: destinationUri,
  });
  return destinationUri;
}

error
Error uploading file: [Error: Call to function 'ExponentFileSystem.copyAsync' has been rejected.
→ Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading androidx.core.content.FileProvider uri content://com.kakao.talk.FileProvider/external_files/emulated/0/Android/data/com.kakao.talk/contents/MTg=/2412.10468v1.pdf from pid=25200, uid=10858 requires the provider be exported, or grantUriPermission()]

+native-intent.ts
export function redirectSystemPath({
  path,
  initial,
}: {
  path: string;
  initial: string;
}) {
  try {
    console.log("redirectSystemPath", path, initial);
    return `/?sharedPath=${encodeURIComponent(path)}`;
  } catch {
    return "/";
  }
}


These are dependencies
"dependencies": {
    "@expo-google-fonts/inter": "^0.2.3",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^14.0.2",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.23.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^7.0.0",
    "axios": "^1.7.7",
    "cookie": "^1.0.1",
    "date-fns": "^4.1.0",
    "expo": "~52.0.19",
    "expo-apple-authentication": "~7.1.2",
    "expo-build-properties": "~0.13.1",
    "expo-constants": "~17.0.3",
    "expo-dev-client": "~5.0.6",
    "expo-document-picker": "~13.0.1",
    "expo-file-system": "~18.0.6",
    "expo-font": "~13.0.1",
    "expo-image": "~2.0.3",
    "expo-linking": "~7.0.3",
    "expo-router": "~4.0.13",
    "expo-share-intent": "^3.1.1",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.29.18",
    "expo-status-bar": "~2.0.0",
    "expo-system-ui": "~4.0.6",
    "expo-web-browser": "~14.0.1",
    "nativewind": "^4.1.23",
    "patch-package": "^8.0.0",
    "react": "18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "18.3.1",
    "react-native": "0.76.5",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.20.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.16.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.12.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^4.0.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.10",
    "react-native-webview": "13.12.5",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.14"
  },

And here is part of xml
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:scheme="moonlight"/>
        <data android:scheme="com.corca.moonlight"/>
        <data android:scheme="exp+moonlight"/>
      </intent-filter>

Already spent more than 24 hours, please help me :)

May be you can try ask permission
const downloadsUri =
FileSystem.StorageAccessFramework.getUriForDirectoryInRoot('directory you need')
  const permissions =
    await FileSystem.StorageAccessFramework.requestDirectoryPermissionsAsync(
      downloadsUri
    )


I also tried this but file provider uri from another app seems unreachable with this function.

But yesterday solved this problem with coding custom native module. Using newIntent function, copying file to cache directory worked. Thank you!
